# Always getting ClassNotFoundException when trying to debug

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, sbt, intellij-14

No matter what I do, when I have an object extending "App" and try to debug I get an error

```
object  Foo extends  App {

  print("here")

}
```

[image]

```
 throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
```

The stack gives absolutely no clues (to me) what is wrong

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be some breakpoints enabled but you are not aware.

Go to `Run > View Breakpoints`

Clear all breakpoints (especially `Java Exception Breakpoints`), and then try to debug again.